# Tweepy filter isn't functioning

Tags: python, filter, tweepy

There is a function in Tweepy if you only want to see the tweets from selected twitter id's.

```
streaming_api.filter(follow=("501088042","107536557",), track=Q)
```

unfortunately it's either not functioning (highly doubtful) or I'm doing something wrong. If I set `follow=None` the script functions perfectly. When I set the user ID's it continues to work as if I've changed nothing. How do I filter my stream to only use the ID's that I set in `follow`?

This is the code:

```
import sys
import tweepy
import webbrowser
import MySQLdb

Q = sys.argv[1:]

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","db" )

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

cur = db.cursor()

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

        try:
            print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text, 
                                      status.author.screen_name, 
                                      status.created_at, 
                                      status.source,)

            cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweets VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (status.text, 
                                                                       status.author.screen_name, 
                                                                       status.created_at, 
                                                                       status.source))

        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)

print >> sys.stderr, 'Filtering the public timeline for "%s"' % (' '.join(sys.argv[1:]),)

streaming_api.filter(follow=("501088042","107536557",), track=Q)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

```
streaming_api.filter(follow=['501088042'], track=Q)
```